# Create alias objects in Test Complete without strict mappings to controls tree

Tags: mapping, alias, testcomplete, autotest

Is it possible to map objects for Test Complete in application (I am testing desktop WPF application) without strict mappings to controls tree? For example: alias objects is based not on mappings but on find functions or smth like that.

So small changes in GUI mappings path (parents deleted or changed) must not affect autotests.

I dig into find functions but not find what I need. So strict mapping to whole tree of parents is used in each autotest.

Note: Each element in WPF tree has unique tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find 'Extended find' attribute in name mapping to state an object that could be find anywhere in the sub-tree of the parent object. That way when the components in the middle of the way are deleted or changed name/structure, your objects will be found unless some properties of the object are changed.
You can use FindChild and FindAll methods on the parent object and find the objects yourself but this practice needs more effort.